# Controller redirect to different paths depending on previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

Question:

How I want to redirect to different path after `create` action, given if previous_page is `../reader/new` goes to `../reader/blog/:id`, whereas if previous_page is `../editor/new` goes to `../editor/blog/:id`.

Explaination:

I want to modify the controller actions so that it can redirect to different path depending on which page it comes from. For example, I have a `reader`, `editor` and `blog` model. Both `reader` and `editor` can create a `blog`.

Here is the original `blogs_controller`:

```
    class BlogsController < ApplicationsController        
      def create
        @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @blog.save
            format.html { redirect_to @blog }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def blog_params
        params.require(:service).permit(:title, :content)
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

- use `redirect_to :back` in the controller if all you need is redirecting **back to the previous page**
- add some logic processing the **HTTP referer**, i.e. decide where to redirect based on `request.referer` in the controller
- **pass the redirection info in a parameter** to the `create` action, e.g. pass `params[:redirect_to] = "reader"` when coming from the "reader" page and decide where to redirect based on this parameter. You can even place the whole URI to redirect into the param and just redirect to it (but this approach is unsafe as params can be mangled by users).

Generally, I'd choose the third option (parameters) as you have the best control over the redirection process (the first two options rely on HTTP referer which can also be mangled by any visitor, thus are potentially unsafe).

Comment: thanks, your first and second option do the trick. But i can't understand the last option. How to pass param[:redirect_to]? Did you put it inside controller `create` action?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `params[:redirect_to[`, let me explain further. For example, I assume you have a form in the `reader/new` action. You can then add a hidden field to this form and set it a symbolic value for the desired redirection, e.g. `hidden_field_tag :redirect_to, "reader"`. Then this param will be passed to the create action as the `params[:redirect_to]` and the controller's `create` action can react on this parameter and redirect to the desired reader page. I fixed the typo in the answer.