# Store data from one table to another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a fundings table and organisations table. Fundings table has organisation_id. In fundings table I have fields that are same with organisations table. What I want is when application is created and on funding show page there is a add button to add all fields that are same in fundings and organisations table gets stored in organisations table as well. Please help

_form.html.erb (funding_form)

```
<%= form_for([@parent, @child, @funding], :html => {class: "form-horizontal",role: "form"}) do |form| %>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :activity_details, class: "required" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_area :activity_details, required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>

<!--Adding organisation -->
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :name_of_organisation, id: "name_of_organisation-label" %>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.text_field :name_of_organisation, class: "form-control hidden", id: "name_of_organisation-textfield" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :address, id: "address-label" %>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.text_field :address, class: "form-control hidden", id: "address-textfield" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :city, id: "city-label" %>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.text_field :city, class: "form-control hidden", id: "city-textfield" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :province, id: "province-label" %>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.text_field :province, class: "form-control hidden", id: "province-textfield" %>
      </div>
    </div>


<!-- End Adding organisation -->        


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= form.submit "Apply", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb(funding show page)

```
<p>
  <strong>Name of Organisation:</strong>
<%= @funding.name_of_organisation %></p><br>
<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
<%= @funding.address %></p><br>
<p>
  <strong>City:</strong>
<%= @funding.city %></p><br>
<p>
  <strong>Province:</strong>
<%= @funding.province %></p><br>
<p>

<% if current_user.admin? %>
        <%= link_to 'Add Organisation', "" %>
<% end %>
```

if admin clicks on add organisation fields get added to organisation table.

schema funding table

```
t.text "activity_details"
t.string "city"
t.string "name_of_organisation"
t.string "province"
t.text "address"
```

schema organisations table

```
t.string "name_of_organisation"
t.text "address"
t.string "city"
t.string "province"
```

funding.rb

```
belongs_to :organisation
```

organisation.rb

```
has_many :fundings
```

organisations controller
I have a new and create method to create organisation by the admin directly.so i have added a new_org method to get add the organisation from the funding table. But I am not able to find out how to implement it.

```
def new_org
    @organisation = Organisation.new
end

def create_org
    @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)
    if @organisation.save
        flash[:success] = "Organisation is added"
        redirect_to main_admin_service_provider_path
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, provide a code of your controller where you tried to implement that. Why do you need a duplicate of some data?

Comment: @Leo  I need to duplicate it because I dont want a normal user to add organisation directly to the organisation table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good way to do it but you can define a hidden form with hidden fields with values of `@funding.x` on show page by defining
`@organization = Organization.new` in show  method on `Fundings.controller` then you can simply post it as normal form. Or you can show this form to only admins.

Comment: how will the post action work for the form. how to define it in the funding controller?

Comment: `  <% form_for(@organization, url: create_organization_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>`  actually you don't need to define `@organization` you can use `form_for(:organization, url: .....)`. Search for  path to create organization in your routes and put it in your form with that `method: :post` parameter.

Comment: <%= form_for(@organisation, :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= f.hidden_field :name_of_organisation, class: "required" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= f.hidden_text_field :name_of_organisation, required: true %>
        </div>
      </div> I tried this. this is the error i get undefined method `hidden_field_tag' for

Comment: `<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, { :value => user.id } %>` you can put some values on inputs like this.

Comment: when I click on submit this the error I get. No route matches [PATCH] "/organisations"

Comment: `<% form_for(@organisation, url: create_organisation_path, method: :post) do |f| %>` you need define which url you are sending this form and which method. For url, look at your routes of your project and find  url_generator method for organisation#create process. If you used `resources :organisations` then the url must be like `organisations_path`.

Comment: <%= form_for(@organisation, url: organisations_path,  :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %> yes this is what I have used. But still getting the error

Comment: Yes I got it . I had not written @organization = Organization.new in funding show controller

Comment: I need to redirect it to the same page after submitting the organisation. It is redirects to the path defined in the create action. def create@organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)if @organisation.saveflash[:success] = "Organisation is added"redirect_to main_admin_service_provider_path
  else 
   render 'new'
  end
 end. I want a different redirection path if organisation is created from funding show page.

Comment: i think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897322/controller-redirect-to-different-paths-depending-on-previous-page) will help you.

Comment: you deleted your comment? that was more helpful to me.

Comment: ah, sorry about that. i thought you have figured out how it must be done. you need to specify both url and method on custom forms and check the url if its available on your project. for example: `<%= form_for(@organisation, url: organisations_path, method::post %>`. if you want to see all available urls on your app just type random stuff like this `localhost:3000/sdfsdf`. Hope it helps.

Comment: organisations GET    /organisations(.:format)                                                                 organisations#index
                              POST   /organisations(.:format)                                                                 organisations#create this is what I have for organisations_path for create

Comment: yeah that is the one you need. organisations_path with post method will go to create method in organisation controller.

Comment: Please help. i am not able to figureout post method. after submit I want it redirected to the same funding show page

Comment: Yes but i dont want it to be redirected to the page mentioned in the create method. I want it to be rediected to the same funding page from where it is created.That create method redirection is set when organisation is created directly not from funding show page

Comment: its hard for me to help you like that but i will try. first change `@organisation` to `:organisation` in your form_for. then add 1 more hidden_field like this  `<%= f.hidden_field :referer, { :value => 'funding' } %>` then in your create method make an if statement like if `params[:referer] == funding` and pick which page you want to  redirect. if that params[:referer] doesn't exist pick another path. Hope it helps.

Comment: no you don't need. you are just sending an extra parameter to controller that's it.with that parameter you can check that where this form sending from

Comment: def create_org@organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)if @organisation.save
   flash[:success] = "Organisation is added"
   if params[:referer] == 'funding'
     redirect_to main_admin_path
      else
    redirect_to main_admin_service_provider_path
   end
  else 
   render 'new'
  end
 end i did like this but it didnt work

Comment: i guess this is happening because you defined a new method named `create_org` but you didn't define a route for it. So now we are sending this form to actual `create` method and it is redirecting to another route. Find or define a route for `create_org` method. This must be solves your problem. I can't tell any better way to solve this problem since i can't see your project completely, sorry.or just modify the `create` method instead of  `create_org`

Comment: Is there any way i can contact you directly?

Comment: I ll drop u an email.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

*app/controllers/fundings_controller.rb*

```
class FundingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_funding, on: %i[show add_organisation]

  # ...

  def update_organisation
    return head :forbidden unless current_user.admin?

    # assuming funding always has an organisation
    whitelist = %w[your field names]
    @funding.organisation.update!(@funding.attributes.slice(*whitelist))
    redirect_to @funding, notice: 'fields successfully added to organisation'
  end

  # ...

  private

  def set_funding
    @funding = Funding.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

*config/routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # ...

  resources :fundings, only: :show do

    # using patch because we are updating an existing resource
    # but you can change this to whatever you like
    patch 'update_organisation', on: :member

  end

  # ...

end
```

*app/views/fundings/show.html.erb*

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
   <%= link_to 'Add Organisation', update_organisation_funding_path(@funding), method: :patch %>
<% end %>
```

---

Alternatively you can update all double fields (without whitelisting) using the following code:

```
double_attribute_names = @funding.attribute_names & @funding.organisation.attribute_names
@funding.organisation.update!(@funding.attributes.slice(*double_attribute_names)
```

**However keep in mind that this may produce unwanted results. For example some fields you don't want to update like `'id'`, `'created_at'`, `'updated_at'` are most likely present on both instances, and maybe some custom double fields.**

This can be resolved by creating a blacklist to exclude those fields:

```
blacklist = %w[id created_at updated_at]
double_attribute_names = @funding.attribute_names & @funding.organisation.attribute_names
@funding.organisation.update!(@funding.attributes.slice(*double_attribute_names).except(*blacklist))
```

But generally speaking it's better to whitelist.

Comment: You might also wan't to handle error. I used [`update!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) which raises an exception if the record is not valid or can't be saved to the database. Resulting in a 500 page in production and an error screen in development mode.